# ng-class and class css/style atrributes

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I do not know when use one over the other and when I should use both at the same time for an html element (div, span, table, etc). Please advise. Mixing both of them may cause some issues, mayn't it?

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) of `ngClass`?

Answer (score 0):

Ngclass is used when you need the class to be conditional based on some logic

Such as ng-class="{'choose-this-class': ifThisAngularScopeIsTrue}"

Class is just a fixed class of css

Answer (score 0):

The **ng-class** directive dynamically binds one or more CSS classes to an HTML element.

Eg: [ng-class](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-class.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You should use class and style attributes as you see fit to your desired designs. The **ng-class** directive is generally used when you want to change some html's class based on some variable or expression.

**Here's a simple example**

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .blue {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
  }
  .red {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div style="height: 100px; width 100%; background-color: red; display: block;" ng-class="{'red': red == true, 'blue': red == false}"></div>
  <br />
  <button ng-click="red = !red">Changing Red to Blue won't work because of the style attribute!</button>
  <br />
  <br />
  <div class="blue" ng-class="{'blue': blue, 'red': !blue}"></div>
  <br />
  <button ng-click="blue = !blue">Toggle between Red & Blue</button>
</div>
```

Notice how inline style attribute overwrites the class ;)

> Do read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for further insight.